# How can I use python to convert a fixed width txt file to csv?

Tags: python, csv, text-files

I searched online, but could not find the answer to my question. I need convert a txt file to a csv. I have figured out how to do this with delimeters, however, the txt file does not have any delimeters or headers so I must set fixed width numbers. The file has millions of records. The widths for the columns are 10, 60, 60, 60, 30, 2, 3, 6, 9, 5, 6, 12, 12, 5, 3, 12, 12, 5, 3.

My two challenges are:
1. To convert the file to csv with the fixed widths listed above.
2. To insert headers.

The data looks something like this:

```
0000000626ISOCKE BBBB ZZZZZ TW DARTMOUTH 10 FDSAF DR DARTMOUTH CASN 7H44DR SAAB -11.111111 22.2222222 000 -33.333333 44.4444444 000
0000000627ISOCKE FFFF TTTTT TW HALIFAX 3367 FDSAF RD HALIFAX CASN 8C5ASE SAAB -55.555555 66.6666666 000 -77.777777 88.8888888 000
0000000628ISOCKE RE CHARLOTTETOWN 449 UYRNT ECSARW RD CHARLOTTETOWN CAPE CSE8HR SAAB -99.999999 11.1111111 000 -22.222222 33.3333333 000
```

Again, all I've been able to is convert the file to csv but not in the correct format using this code:

```
import csv
rf = open(r'C:\Users\...New Folder\practice.txt', 'r') #input file handle
wf = open(r'C:\Users\...New Folder\Book1.csv','w') #output file handle
writer = csv.writer(wf)

for row in rf.readlines():
    writer.writerow(row.split())
rf.close() # close input file handle
wf.close() # close output file handle
```

Comment: in your for loop why dont you just write
`for row in rf` instead of `for row in rf.readlines()`

Comment: Thats how I saw the code that I found online. Would that make a difference to my problem though?

Comment: about `readlines`: Keeping a list of millions of strings in memory when you don't need to is likely to engender other problems.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) to tear each fixed-width row apart, trimming where appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Im a newbie though. Could you show me an example?

Comment: `>>> struct.unpack('6s5s3s', '000001foo  123')`
`('000001', 'foo  ', '123')`

Answer (score 4):

Use slice objects:

```
>>> widths = 1,2,3
>>> slices = []
>>> offset = 0
>>> for w in widths:
...     slices.append(slice(offset, offset + w))
...     offset += w
...
>>> slices
[slice(0, 1, None), slice(1, 3, None), slice(3, 6, None)]
>>> pieces = ["abcdef"[slice] for slice in slices]
>>> pieces
['a', 'bc', 'def']
>>>
```

Comment: Set up `slices` once at the start of your code. For each line in your file, do `fields = [line[slice] for slice in slices]`

Answer (score 4):

If any one is still looking for a solution, I have developed a small script in python. its easy to use provided you have python 3.5

https://github.com/just10minutes/FixedWidthToDelimited/blob/master/FixedWidthToDelimiter.py

```
"""
This script will convert Fixed width File into Delimiter File, tried on Python 3.5 only
Sample run: (Order of argument doesnt matter)
python ConvertFixedToDelimiter.py -i SrcFile.txt -o TrgFile.txt -c Config.txt -d "|"
Inputs are as follows
1. Input FIle - Mandatory(Argument -i) - File which has fixed Width data in it
2. Config File - Optional (Argument -c, if not provided will look for Config.txt file on same path, if not present script will not run)
    Should have format as
    FieldName,fieldLength
    eg:
    FirstName,10
    SecondName,8
    Address,30
    etc:
3. Output File - Optional (Argument -o, if not provided will be used as InputFIleName plus Delimited.txt)
4. Delimiter - Optional (Argument -d, if not provided default value is "|" (pipe))
"""
from collections import OrderedDict
import argparse
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import os.path
import sys


def slices(s, args):
    position = 0
    for length in args:
        length = int(length)
        yield s[position:position + length]
        position += length

def extant_file(x):
    """
    'Type' for argparse - checks that file exists but does not open.
    """
    if not os.path.exists(x):
        # Argparse uses the ArgumentTypeError to give a rejection message like:
        # error: argument input: x does not exist
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("{0} does not exist".format(x))
    return x





parser = ArgumentParser(description="Please provide your Inputs as -i InputFile -o OutPutFile -c ConfigFile")
parser.add_argument("-i", dest="InputFile", required=True,    help="Provide your Input file name here, if file is on different path than where this script resides then provide full path of the file", metavar="FILE", type=extant_file)
parser.add_argument("-o", dest="OutputFile", required=False,    help="Provide your Output file name here, if file is on different path than where this script resides then provide full path of the file", metavar="FILE")
parser.add_argument("-c", dest="ConfigFile", required=False,   help="Provide your Config file name here,File should have value as fieldName,fieldLength. if file is on different path than where this script resides then provide full path of the file", metavar="FILE",type=extant_file)
parser.add_argument("-d", dest="Delimiter", required=False,   help="Provide the delimiter string you want",metavar="STRING", default="|")

args = parser.parse_args()

#Input file madatory
InputFile = args.InputFile
#Delimiter by default "|"
DELIMITER = args.Delimiter

#Output file checks
if args.OutputFile is None:
    OutputFile = str(InputFile) + "Delimited.txt"
    print ("Setting Ouput file as "+ OutputFile)
else:
    OutputFile = args.OutputFile

#Config file check
if args.ConfigFile is None:
    if not os.path.exists("Config.txt"):
        print ("There is no Config File provided exiting the script")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        ConfigFile = "Config.txt"
        print ("Taking Config.txt file on this path as Default Config File")
else:
    ConfigFile = args.ConfigFile

fieldNames = []
fieldLength = []
myvars = OrderedDict()


with open(ConfigFile) as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        name, var = line.partition(",")[::2]
        myvars[name.strip()] = int(var)
for key,value in myvars.items():
    fieldNames.append(key)
    fieldLength.append(value)

with open(OutputFile, 'w') as f1:
    fieldNames = DELIMITER.join(map(str, fieldNames))
    f1.write(fieldNames + "\n")
    with open(InputFile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            rec = (list(slices(line, fieldLength)))
            myLine = DELIMITER.join(map(str, rec))
            f1.write(myLine + "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, your code helped me in another requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

for me personally the FixedWidth module worked very well.

See https://pypi.org/project/FixedWidth/

It takes a bit of setup, however, you can then describe your fields to be string, numeric (with ability to specify precision), left aligned, right aligned, what is the pad character for each field, etc.

quite powerful, especially if you need to parse note than 1 type of file: you just supply the expected field descriptions and it does everything else.